# Doing a search/loading custom results into ember store?

Tags: ember.js

Been doing some searching and reading the source code of ember-data but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. So my index page loads the data like so:

```
App.SaleRecordsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', App.SaleRecord.find());
  }
});
```

On the server, i simply respond with the latest 10 records. What i also want to do, is query the same url, passing a single search field. This search field or criteria is checked against a few fields in the database. These fields are across a couple different models in the join statement, so i don't think i can just do:

```
App.SaleRecord.find({ book.title: critera });
```

Book being the belongsTo record.

In the controller for that route, here's what i have for querying the data at least, which works as expected:

```
App.SaleRecordsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  search: function() {
    $.getJSON('/search?criteria=' + $('.criteria').val(), function(data) {

    });
  }
});
```

But I'm unsure of what to do from here.

1. If some of the records are already in the store due to being part of the last 10 results, do i need to unload them first?
2. How do i load the data into the store from the json hash? I know how to create a record and populate it, so i can loop through the data, but i wonder if there's  one liner for it.

Thanks. I hope the question was clear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to find an answer, mainly thanks to this question/answer here: [Ember.js Ajax call is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653525/ember-js-ajax-call-is-not-working-as-expected)

I moved the ajax call out of the controller and into a model function. So like in the linked question, i made a custom function to call in the controller:

```
LocalBookFinder.SaleRecord = DS.Model.extend({
  isbn: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  condition: DS.attr('string'),
  book: DS.belongsTo('LocalBookFinder.Book')
});

LocalBookFinder.SaleRecord.reopenClass({
  search: function(criteria) {
    var result = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});
    var _this = this;
    $.getJSON('/search?criteria=' + criteria, function(data) {
      var ids = [];
      var arr = data.sale_records;
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var sale_record = arr[i];
        if(ids.indexOf(sale_record.book_id) == -1) {
          ids.push(sale_record.book_id);
        }
      }

      var ajax_count = ids.length;
      var sale_records = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("/books/" + ids[i], function(data) {
          for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            var sale_record = arr[j];
            if(sale_record.book_id == data.book.id) {
              sale_record.book = data.book;
              sale_records.push(sale_record);
            }
          }
          if(i == ajax_count) {
            console.log(sale_records);
            result.set('content', sale_records);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

Then in the controller, i simply do:

```
search: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var result = LocalBookFinder.SaleRecord.search($('.criteria').val());
  this.set('content', result);
}
```

I think the first ajax bit of the search function in the model is pretty straight forward. It requests the data, and sets an empty ember array proxy to store it in. Now, since i am loading the book image and title from a child record, i need to call those separately. So with the first result set, i populate an array of book ids that i need to request. With each ajax call, i go through the array of sale records, and set the book property to the resulting hash data. Once it's done (via a counter) i set the result content with the JSON data.