# Ember.js Ajax call is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js framework.

I was trying to do a ajax call with from the Framework and not getting value as expected.

Below is the code in Page -

Link to first ajax call and it is working as expected.

```
{{#linkTo listemployee class="span3 btn btn-large btn-block"}}Employees{{/linkTo}}
```

Call data to populate the table -

```
App.ListemployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller) {
        $.getJSON('data/Tutorials.json', function(data) {
            controller.set('content',data);
        });
      }
    });
```

And the template for the data -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listemployee">
  <h3 class="demo-panel-title">This is the list for Employee</h3>
  <table border=2>
    <tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Address</b> </td><td><b> Phone</b></td><td colspan=3>Action<td></tr>
    {{#each item in content}}
      <tr><td>{{item.name}}</td><td>{{item.address}} </td><td> {{item.phone}}</td><td> {{#linkTo viewemployee item.name}}View{{/linkTo}} </td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
    {{/each}}
   </table>
</script>
```

The above is working as expected.

But when I clicked to

```
{{#linkTo viewemployee item.name}}View{{/linkTo}}
```

for above section -

My Controller code is in App.js -

```
App.Router.map(function() {
      this.route("listemployee", { path: "/employees" });
      this.resource("viewemployee", {
        path: "/employees/:name"
      });
    });
```

And my `ViewemployeeRoute` is

```
App.ViewemployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {
        return {name: params.name};
      },
      setupController: function(controller, model) {
        $.getJSON('data/Tutorials.json', function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item){
                if(item.name === model.name)
                {
                    var tabledata = '<table border = \"1\" ><tr><td>Name</td><td>'+item.name+'</td></tr><tr><td>Address</td><td>'+item.address+'</td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td>'+item.phone+'</td></tr></table>';
                    $('#employeetable').html(tabledata);
                    controller.set('content',item);
                }
            });
        });
      }
    });
```

and my template code is -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="viewemployee">
  <h3 class="demo-panel-title">This is the View Employee template</h3>
  <div id = "employeetable">

  </div>
</script>
```

The Problem -

**The data for the employee is not coming when I am clicking on the `View` Link for first time.**

**But when I refresh the page, the data is coming as expected.**

I think the problem is, when I click on the `View` link the response from ajax is coming later after page rendering.

So, what should I do in code, so that I have the Employee Related Details on clicking the `View` link?

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks.

**Update 2 after trying from the answer. But still the same result is coming.**

I have changed My app.js as follows -

```
App.ListemployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
        model: function() {
            return App.Employee.findAll();
        }
    });

    App.ViewemployeeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {
        return App.Employee.find(params);
      }
    });

    App.Employee.reopenClass({
      findAll: function() {
        var result = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
          url: 'data/Tutorials.json',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            result.set('content', data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
          }
        });
        return result;
      },
      find: function(params) {
        var result = Ember.Object.create({content: null});
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
          url: 'data/Tutorials.json',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                data.forEach(function(item){
                    if(item.name === params.name)
                    {
                        result.set('content', item);
                    }
                });
            },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('not found');
          }
        });
        return result;
      }
    });
```

And the my data file is -

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "John's Home",
        "phone": "John's Phone"
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry",
        "address": "Harry's Home",
        "phone": "Harry's Phone"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tom",
        "address": "Tom's Home",
        "phone": "Tom's Phone"
    }
]
```

we can find the work here -

http://www.phloxblog.in/ember-crud-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the view and pass a model via the #linkTo the model part of your route is not executed as it already knows the model.

Also, as a general rule, it's better to do the ajax calls in the model, not in the route.

```
App.ProjectsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
  model: function() {
    return App.Project.findAll();
  }
});

App.Project.reopenClass({
  findAll: function() {
    var result = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/projects.json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'user_id': App.currentUser.id},
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        result.set('content', data.projects);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });

    return result;
  },

  find: function(project_id) {
    var result = Ember.Object.create({content: null, isLoaded: false});
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/projects/' + project_id + '.json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        result.setProperties(data.project);
        result.set('isLoaded', true);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('not found');
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have edited my Question as per your update. But still the problem did not solved. Can you work through this code and give me some direction.

Comment: I have to add that I'm not sure how that would work when the ajax calls won't finish before the return statement. Does one perhaps have to hook in to the model object itself instead of doing a return?

Comment: @agmcleod You'll need to use promises in order to get it to work correctly.

Comment: @PiyasDe I'm not sure what the issue is. One thing I notice is that in the find(param) you set the content to item but you dont' have a content property defined in result

Comment: @Rudi I have changed the object with content as parameter also. That also did not solved the Problem. Anyway, thanks for your valuable suggestions.