# Load data from controller in ember.js

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, loading

I want to implement a system that shows me the newest posts. For this I do not want to use the index action from the user as this is already taken for another post function but a "newest" action. It is showed on the index route with a `{{ render "postNewest" }}` call. I would prefer to load the data in the PostNewestController or PostNewestView instead of the route for abstraction reasons.
I tried two ideas to achieve this, but none worked so far:

- create a custom adapter and add a `findNewest()` method: the `findNewest()` method is sadly not found when trying to call in the init method of the controller.
- write the request directly into the init method and then update with `store.loadMany(payload)`: data is successful request. However, I do not know how to access the data from the template and set the content of the controller.

Is there any way for this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the source code to better understand the problem:

*PostModel.js*

```
App.Post.reopenClass({
    stream: function(items) {
        var result = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: [] });
        var items = [];
        $.getJSON("/api/v1/post/stream?auth_token=" + App.Auth.get("authToken"), function(payload) {
            result.set('content', payload.posts);
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

*PostStreamController.js*

```
App.PostStreamController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.set("content", App.Post.stream());
    },
});
```

*index.hbs*

```
{{# if App.Auth.signedIn}}
    {{ render "dashboard" }}
{{else}}
    {{ render "GuestHeader" }}
{{/if}}

{{ render "postStream" }}
```

*postStream.hbs*

```
{{#each post in model}}
    <li>{{#linkTo 'post.show' post data-toggle="tooltip"}}{{post.name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{else}}
    Nothing's there!
{{/each}}
```

*PostShowRoute.js*

```
App.PostShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Post.find(params.post_id);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The Post model has a belongsTo relationship to another model. This relationship is not loaded by Ember so in the stream() method I have to load this manually. Then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I Had this issue too. Just add `init` in your controller, and define the model you want to get there.

**In your Controller**

```
App.PostRecentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  init: function() {
    return this.set('content', App.Post.find({
      recent: true
    }));
  }
});
```

**In your template**

```
{{#each post in content}}
    {{post.body}}
{{/each}}
```

I would recommend you check EMBER EXTENSION, it will give you a good idea of the naming, and see if everything is missing.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I managed to work around the issue like presented there [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388825/doing-a-search-loading-custom-results-into-ember-store). The problem I am now faced with is that when clicking on a post the model is not working. I think the problem is that I return an array instead of an model.

Comment: What do you want to do when you click the post?

Comment: Simply show it as when loading the PostShowRoute manually per URL. I use `{{#linkTo "post.show" post}}`. The URL is generated correctly but after clicking the page stays blank.

Comment: If by stays blank you mean its empty, then the template is empty or you're or you're working on the wrong template.

Comment: This is strange, because when typing the same URL into the browser and hitting Return (or simply refreshing the blank page) the content is correctly loaded and displayed. The post.show template is not empty...

Comment: Ok, little update: The route is in fact the correct one, but the model parameter is not passed on this specific link. On other links in the app it passes the model correctly.

Comment: Can you post some code please. It would be so much easier to understand.

Comment: I added the source code. Hopefully everything necessary is included

Comment: Sorry. I really don't know what's the problem. But try to replace `App.Post.stream()` with `App.Post.find()` and see if it works